# Vagrant Authentication failure after packaging - private key missing

Tags: ssh, vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox, virtualization

I create VM with vagrant starting from a base box centos-6.5. 
I made some changes, then I removed the file /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules from the guest and packaged it. I added the new box to vagrant  and started up:

```
vagrant package --base vm_name
vagrant box add centos-6.5_mine package.box
vagrant up
```

Vagrant is not able to ssh the new VM:

```
default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
```

I noticed that the file

```
.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key
```

is missing in the new vm's 
vagrant folder. Adding the private_key from the initial vm's folder does the trick but it is still not a solution: the new vm does not work out of the box.

Does anybody know how to solve this ?

thanks

Comment: What's SO you are using in your host? Is Windows? Your guest base centos-6.5 is 32 or 64 bits?

Comment: Hi. Host is fedora21. Guest is 64.

Answer (score 4):

In order to be able to distribute the vm and make it work out of the box (insecurely), I added the vagrant public key (https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/tree/master/keys) to .ssh/authorized_keys. 
Users of the box do not need to add any additional ssh configuration to get started.

Answer (score 0):

You can try  [SSH Settings](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/vagrantfile/ssh_settings.html) in your Vagrantfile

`config.ssh.private_key_path = 'path/your_private_key'`

`config.ssh.insert_key = false`